# Como jogar um var dentro de return?

Tags: javascript, return

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(a,b){
  var tNC = a.length + " ".length + b.length;
  return tNC;
}

tamanhoNomeCompleto("Paulo","Paulada");
```

Como eu faço para colocar o `tNC` no `return`?

Pois estou recebendo isso:

> `tamanhoNomeCompleto` usa variáveis ​​locais desnecessárias você pode retornar a expressão diretamente

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Isso?

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(a, b){
    return a.length + b.length + 1;
}

console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto("Paulo", "Paulada"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FullLength.js).

A [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é totalmente desnecessária aí então é só transportar a expressão para o `return`.

Variáveis servem para guardar valores, se não precisa guardar não crie uma, use o valor que está guardando nela diretamente onde precisa.

Note que eu não peguei o tamanho do espaço porque ele é conhecido (não sei se todos navegadores ou Node faria otimização disto.

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, eu estava ficando maluco para descobrir como fazer isso no return, pois estou aprendendo e fico muito puto quando não encontro a resposta para meu problema. E vc ensinou como eu uso console.log para função que não conseguia ver!

Comment: @MarcelRobertoPiesigilli veja o [tour] sobre a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.